# extract x and y axis from plot

Tags: export, labeling

I am trying to write a function that read what is the FrameLabel of a plot and translates that to filesystem friendly name, that, for instance does not contain "/" or greek characters  and so on ...

The goal is to get a function that exports a plot to PDF and automatically gives it a meaningful file name of the type XAxisLabel_YAxisLabel_PlotLabel.pdf

Here is what I got so far.

1) a translation for unwanted character and strings:

```
  FileSystemFriendly={\left->,\right->,\text{->,$->,\{->,\}->, ->,\->,{->,}->,/->.over.,>->.gt.,<->.lt.,=->.eq.}
```

2)   a function that actually takes the plot and looks for the labels

```
  PlotAutoExport[inputplot_]:=Module[{res,respath},
      res=Export[StringReplace[ToString[TeXForm[FrameLabel/. inputplot[[2]]]],FileSystemFriendly]<>__<>StringReplace[ToString[TeXForm[PlotLabel/. inputplot[[2]]]],FileSystemFriendly]<>.pdf,inputplot];
      Print[File put in,respath=Directory[]<>/<>res];
      Button[Open it!,SystemOpen[respath]]
    ]
```

This is giving some acceptable results so far, which means that the filenames are usable on a regular filesystem. However the typical name is plenty of garbage, for instance for a very simple label I still get `(beginarraycc1-Cumulative&Nonep_T,j_ 3&Noneendarray)__PlotLabel`
which has lots of stuff that I do not know where it comes from. I could chase and remove one by one the unwanted stuff but I feel like I am not doing it the right way. Hence I wanted to ask for some advice.

Thanks for sharing your knowledge,
Roberto

Comment: You should post code for some of the offending plots as well to make reproduction of the problem possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
plt1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2},
  PlotLabel -> "Function Plot",
  AxesLabel -> {x, f[x]}]
```

[image]

```
plt2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2},
  PlotLabel -> "Function Plot",
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
  FrameLabel -> {x, f[x]}]
```

[image]

Here is a skeleton for the file name

```
fileName[plt_] :=
 StringReplace[
    StringJoin@
     Riffle[
      ToString /@ (({
             Reverse[FrameLabel], AxesLabel, PlotLabel} /.
            AbsoluteOptions[plt]) /.
          None -> Sequence[] //
         Flatten),
      "_"],
    " " -> ""] <> ".pdf" //
  Quiet

fileName[plt1]
```

> "x_f[x]_FunctionPlot.pdf"

```
fileName[plt2]
```

> "x_f[x]_FunctionPlot.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Bob's answer, but this is how I would write it:

```
plt2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> "Function Plot", Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {x, f[x]}]

fileName[{plabel_, {{ylabel_, _}, {xlabel_, _}}}] := Module[{clean},
  clean = StringReplace[ToString@#, Except[LetterCharacter] -> ""] & /@ {plabel, ylabel, xlabel};
  StringJoin[Riffle[clean, "_"], ".pdf"]
  ]

fileName[{PlotLabel, FrameLabel} /. Options[plt2]]
(* Out: "FunctionPlot_fx_x.pdf" *)
```

You can change `Except[LetterCharacter] -> ""` to something else or add allowed characters to that list. Currently it will remove any characters that aren't letters.